# Are there anybody use Android based 4G module

Tags: hardware, mobile-data, android

Are there anybody who used android based 4G module, I have found out a 4G module based on Android system and support 2nd develop, which means we can use the application processor on there module and we don't need to use separated application processor and 4G module(data modem).

http://www.new-mobi.com/product/showproduct.php?lang=en&id=30
Can I use this module to make a POS machine?  thank you!

Comment: Hi Jin, Welcome to the site. This doesn't look like a question which can really be answered in a constructive way. If you want to do more research and ask a specific question (about IoT, not just about mobile data), we can try and help.

Comment: Running Android on embedded/smart devices does offer some interesting possibilities, but custom Android implementations can be very painful even with experience and documentation.  Starting with a poorly documented board and (what appears to be) little relevant experience is probably going to be an exercise in pointless frustration.  Whatever you do, make sure you the vendor (or else existing online resources) can show you how to build, install, and run the full Linux + Android stack **from source** before you invest any effort in customization or buying multiple copies of hardware.

Comment: Also, if you are associated with the vendor, it's polite to disclose this.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane I am sorry, I ask this question is to make a research. I want to know Is there anybody using this kind of module to develop. thank you.

Comment: @Jin.Liu I think the issue here is that your question would be more suited to a forum (discussing things, asking if other people have experiences), which doesn't really work on this **Q&A** site. If you can rephrase this into a clear question (see [ask]), then feel free to flag for this to be reopened.